# Fabric surpresses stdout being written to screen

Tags: python, fabric

The next command in Fabric will not print the output to stdout.
I have to manually type print output to print the output after execution (can take 10 minutes)
Any ideas?

```
 with settings(warn_only=False), shell_env(ALLOWED_CHANGES="10"):
     if logfilename is  None:
         logfilename = "/tmp/deploy/deleteme"
     output = local("ALLOWED_CHANGES=1 bin/stack {dry} -d {env} -t {stack} --{op} 2>&1 | tee -a {log}".format(
         dry=dry,
         env=environ,
         stack=stack,
         log=logfilename,
         op=operation,
     ),
         capture=True
     )
     print "Output: "+output
```

Comment: To help reproducing this, what versions of Python/Fabric are you using?

Comment: This is expected.  `local` does not print output when `capture` is `True`.

Answer (score 0):

[This is expected](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.14/api/core/operations.html#fabric.operations.local).  `local` will not print output if `capture` is `True`:

> **`local`** is not currently capable of simultaneously printing and capturing output, as **`run`**/**`sudo`** do. The `capture` kwarg allows you to switch between printing and capturing as necessary, and defaults to `False`.